# Kotlin: How to create a string by repeating a character a given number of times

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin, runtime

I am trying to print a line below a title. The idea is that the line is the same length as the title. I have tried several ways and I think this is the closest, but the result it gives me is not correct.

```
fun main() {

    val chapters = arrayOf("Basic syntax", "Idioms", "Kotlin by example", "Coding conventions")

    for (numCharpter in chapters.indices){
        // Print the name of the chapter
        val title = "Charpter ${numCharpter + 1}: ${chapters[numCharpter]}"
        val arrayDash = Array(title.length) {'='}
        val stringDash = arrayDash.toString()


        println("$title\n$stringDash\n")

        // the rest of the code
    }
}
```

the output i want is:

```
Charpter 1: Basic syntax
========================

Charpter 2: Idioms
==================

Charpter 3: Kotlin by example
=============================

Charpter 4: Coding conventions
==============================
```

the output i get is:

```
Charpter 1: Basic syntax
[Ljava.lang.Character;@24d46ca6
Charpter 2: Idioms
[Ljava.lang.Character;@4517d9a3
Charpter 3: Kotlin by example
[Ljava.lang.Character;@372f7a8d
Charpter 4: Coding conventions
[Ljava.lang.Character;@2f92e0f4
```

Is there a simple way to initialize a String by repeating a character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val chapters = arrayOf("Basic syntax", "Idioms", "Kotlin by example", "Coding conventions")

for (numCharpter in chapters.indices) {
  val title = "Chapter ${numCharpter + 1}: ${chapters[numCharpter]}"
  val line = "=".repeat(title.length)
  println("$title\n$line\n")
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot

Comment: I added a second solution which avoids the two local variables _title_ and _line._

Answer (score 2):

```
val chapters = arrayOf("Basic syntax", "Idioms", "Kotlin by example", "Coding conventions")

val titles = chapters.mapIndexed { index, chapter ->
  "Chapter ${index + 1}: $chapter".let { it + "\n" + "=".repeat(it.length) + "\n" }
}

for (title in titles) {
  println(title)
}
```

Or more readable:

```
val chapters = arrayOf("Basic syntax", "Idioms", "Kotlin by example", "Coding conventions")

val titles = chapters
  .mapIndexed { index, chapter ->
    "Chapter ${index + 1}: $chapter"
      .let { title ->
        buildString {
          append(title)
          append("\n")
          append("=".repeat(title.length))
          append("\n")
        }
      }
  }

for (title in titles) {
  println(title)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A further simplified variation of the solution of @lukas.j might look like this:

```kotlin
val chapters = arrayOf("Basic syntax", "Idioms", "Kotlin by example", "Coding conventions")
val titles = chapters
    .mapIndexed { index, chapter ->
        buildString {
            append("Chapter ${index + 1}: $chapter")
            append('\n')
            repeat(length - 1) { append('=') }
            append("\n")
        }
    }
      
titles.forEach { println(it) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another version with a shoutout to our good buddy `print`, you can just keep printing characters on the same line. (Not saying this is the *best* way here, but it's good to know your options!)

```
chapters.forEachIndexed { i, title ->
    val heading = "Chapter ${i + 1}: $title"
    println(heading)
    repeat(heading.length) { print('=') }
    print("\n\n")
}
```

So it's organised like how it's formatted - print your header, print your underline, then print whatever line separators you need. I think that's pretty easy to read and work with (and would probably make for a good separate function).

If you don't like that the break for the `=====` line is rolled into the final separator formatting line, you could always do something like

```
repeat(heading.length) { print('=') }.also { print("\n") } // or println()
```

if you wanted. Or `run` or `let`, it doesn't matter, `also` just reads like "oh and then this at the end"